# how to set an smaallest image as windowBackground keeping aspect ratio

Tags: android, window, background-image, aspect-ratio, bitmapdrawable

seeking experts attention.. I wanna set an image(which is smaller than
device screen resulation) as background of my
app .. I want it to fill the entire window but
keeping the ascpect ratio of image... (if the
image aspect ratio doesn't match with window
aspect ratio, image will be cropped) .

NOTE:this is possible, see Contacs+ app..they did it..No matter how small the is, it fill the window, keeps aspect ratio(doesn't stretch) and the rest of the image is cropped.
Can anybody
give me sollution for this